# JavaScript variable assignments from tuples

Tags: javascript, tuples, destructuring

In other languages like Python 2 and Python 3, you can define and assign values to a tuple variable, and retrieve their values like this:

```
tuple = ("Bob", 24)
name, age = tuple
print(name)           #name evaluates to Bob
print(age)            #age evaluates to 24
```

Is there anything similar in JavaScript? Or do I just have to do it the ugly way with an array:

```
tuple = ["Bob", 24]
name = tuple[0]       //name Evaluates to Bob
age = tuple[1]        //age Evaluates to 24
```

Is there a better way to simulate Python tuples in JavaScript 5?

**Update:** See the answer regarding ES6, which should be favored over CoffeeScript for new projects.

Comment: In JavaScript, don't forget to declare the variables: `var tuple, name, age;`

Comment: `var name=tuple[0], age=tuple[1];`  It's a bit more typing, but *ugly* might be an overstatement.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

JavaScript 1.7 added [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which allows you to do essentially what you are after:

```
function getTuple(){
   return ["Bob", 24];
}
var [a, b] = getTuple();
// a === "bob" , b === 24 are both true
```

Answer (score 51):

You have to do it the ugly way. If you *really* want something like this, you can check out [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which has that and a whole lot of other features that make it look more like python (sorry for making it sound like an advertisement, but I really like it.)

Comment: Hmm, this is quite interesting, just ran up on this scenario myself, as JavaScript doesn't seem to provide obvious tuple support, and coming from an intense period of functional programming, you develop the want for tuples.  I also just found this, but not sure if it works, it just looked good in terms of tuple support too:  http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/arrowlets/api-tuples.xhtml.  I'll definitely look at CoffeeScript.

Comment: would be great to update this answer, lots of CoffeeScript ideas have been already port to javascript, no need anymore for CoffeeScript

Answer (score 35):

You can do something similar:

```
var tuple = Object.freeze({ name:'Bob', age:14 })
```

and then refer to name and age as attributes

```
tuple.name 
tuple.age
```

Comment: I won't downvote but technically this is incorrect. You can still change (ie mutate) the values of tuple.name and tuple.age after the object is declared. By definition immutable types can non be changed after they're defined. They're like read-only types where both the parameters and their values can only be declared once.

Comment: @EvanPlaice if mutability is an issue, you could use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), i.e.: `tuple = Object.freeze({ name:'Bob', age:14 })`

Comment: @canon I agree, that's probably the only acceptable/correct approach in this whole thread. Unfortunately, mcm's answer doesn't freeze the object so it's still mutable.

Comment: @EvanPlaice I don't see where the issue of mutability came from - tuples aren't immutable in the original Python example!

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster The difference between a list and a tuple in Python is, a list is mutable whereas a tuple is not. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences. Tuples aren't natively supported in JavaScript because all JS data structures are mutable unless you call Object.freeze() on the object after creation.

Comment: @EvanPlaice whoah, my bad, I could have sworn tuple elements were assignable. TIL!

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster Yep, and since a tuple's structure is fixed after creation their values can be accessed faster in languages that natively support them.

Comment: @evan-plaice Strings and numbers are naturally immutable in JavaScript, although I wouldn’t call them data structures

Comment: @gabssnake The values are, the references to those values aren't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248568/javascript-numbers-immutable. An object will only be made immutable if Object.freeze() is applied. If the object has properties that are also objects you would then have to call freeze on all of the children (and recursively on all children of children) as well. An object is **not** the equivalent of a tuple.

Comment: @evan-plaice Strange first sentence. Do you disagree that strings and numbers are immutable in JavaScript ? Care to provide an example of mutation with these types ?

Comment: @evan-plaice I was originally commenting on your statement on mutability of *all* JS data structures

Answer (score 32):

This "tuple" feature it is called destructuring in EcmaScript2015 and is soon to be supported by up to date browsers. For the time being, [only Firefox and Chrome support it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

But hey, you can use a [transpiler](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20tuple%20%3D%20%5B%22Bob%22%2C%2024%5D%0Alet%20%5Bname%2C%20age%5D%20%3D%20touple%0A%0Aconsole.log(name)%0Aconsole.log(age)%0A).

The code would look as nice as python:

```
let tuple = ["Bob", 24]
let [name, age] = tuple

console.log(name)
console.log(age)
```

Comment: To future readers: this feature is supported in chrome since chrome 49 (according to the Mozilla docs). You can also check compatibility using the Mozilla docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 17):

A frozen array behaves identically to a python tuple:

```
const tuple = Object.freeze(["Bob", 24]);
let [name, age]; = tuple
console.debug(name); // "Bob"
console.debug(age); // 24
```

Be fancy and define a class

```
class Tuple extends Array { 
  constructor(...items) { 
    super(...items); 
    Object.freeze(this);
  } 
}

let tuple = new Tuple("Jim", 35);
let [name, age] = tuple;
console.debug(name); // Jim
console.debug(age); // 35
tuple = ["Bob", 24]; // no effect 
console.debug(name); // Jim
console.debug(age); // 25
```

Works today in all the latest browsers.

Comment: Couldn't you just set it to a const? The const is immutable, no?

Comment: No. The const is not reassignable. You can't do const tuple = ["Jim", 35]; tuple = ["James", 35]. You can do const tuple = ["Jim", 35]; tuple[0] = "James"; Therefore it is not immutable.

Answer (score 8):

**Tuples aren't supported in JavaScript**

If you're looking for an immutable list, Object.freeze() can be used to make an array immutable.

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In essence the object is made effectively immutable. The method returns the object being frozen.

*Source: [Mozilla Developer Network - Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)*

**Assign an array as usual but lock it using 'Object.freeze()**

```
> tuple = Object.freeze(['Bob', 24]);
[ 'Bob', 24 ]
```

**Use the values as you would a regular array (python multi-assignment is not supported)**

```
> name = tuple[0]
'Bob'
> age = tuple[1]
24
```

**Attempt to assign a new value**

```
> tuple[0] = 'Steve'
'Steve'
```

**But the value is not changed**

```
> console.log(tuple)
[ 'Bob', 24 ]
```

Comment: On a side-note hopefully Tuples will get first-class support in ES6. True native tuple (ie heterogenous sequence) will also improve speed.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can't use that tuple assignment syntax in (ECMA|Java)Script.

EDIT: Someone linked to Mozilla/JS 1.7 - this wouldn't work cross-browser but if that is not required then there's your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is not intended to be actually used in real life, just an interesting exercise. See [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) for details.

This is the closest you can get without resorting to vendor-specific extensions:

```
myArray = [1,2,3];
eval(set('a,b,c = myArray'));
```

Helper function:

```
function set(code) {
    var vars=code.split('=')[0].trim().split(',');
    var array=code.split('=')[1].trim();
    return 'var '+vars.map(function(x,i){return x+'='+array+'['+i+']'}).join(',');
}
```

Proof that it works in arbitrary scope:

```
(function(){
    myArray = [4,5,6];
    eval(set('x,y,z = myArray'));
    console.log(y);  // prints 5
})()
```

`eval` is not supported in Safari.

Comment: +1 for being super clever, don't ever use this in real life though :-p

Answer (score 4):

As an update to The Minister's answer, you can now do this with es2015:

```
function Tuple(...args) {
  args.forEach((val, idx) => 
    Object.defineProperty(this, "item"+idx, { get: () => val })
  )
}


var t = new Tuple("a", 123)
console.log(t.item0) // "a"
t.item0 = "b"
console.log(t.item0) // "a"
```

https://jsbin.com/fubaluwimo/edit?js,console

Comment: There is no reason why you couldn't do this before ES2015... Also this does not answer the OP's question, he asked for destructuring

Answer (score 3):

You can have a tuple type in Javascript as well. Just define it with higher order functions (the academic term is Church encoding):

```js
const Tuple = (...args) => {
  const Tuple = f => f(...args);
  return Object.freeze(Object.assign(Tuple, args));
};

const get1 = tx => tx((x, y) => x);

const get2 = tx => tx((x, y) => y);

const bimap = f => g => tx => tx((x, y) => Tuple(f(x), g(y)));

const toArray = tx => tx((...args) => args);

// aux functions

const inc = x => x + 1;
const toUpperCase = x => x.toUpperCase();

// mock data

const pair = Tuple(1, "a");

// application

console.assert(get1(pair) === 1);
console.assert(get2(pair) === "a");

const {0:x, 1:y} = pair;
console.log(x, y); // 1 a

console.log(toArray(bimap(inc) (toUpperCase) (pair))); // [2, "A"]

const map = new Map([Tuple(1, "a"), Tuple(2, "b")]);
console.log(map.get(1), map.get(2)); // a b
```

Please note that `Tuple` isn't used as a normal constructor. The solution doesn't rely on the prototype system at all, but solely on higher order functions.

What are the advantages of tuples over `Array`s used like tuples? Church encoded tuples are immutable by design and thus prevent side effects caused by mutations. This helps to build more robust applications. Additionally, it is easier to reason about code that distinguishes between `Array`s as a collection type (e.g. `[a]`) and tuples as related data of various types (e.g. `(a, b)`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Javascript Tuple implementation:

```
var Tuple = (function () {
   function Tuple(Item1, Item2) {
      var item1 = Item1;
      var item2 = Item2;
      Object.defineProperty(this, "Item1", {
          get: function() { return item1  }
      });
      Object.defineProperty(this, "Item2", {
          get: function() { return item2  }
      });
   }
   return Tuple;
})();

var tuple = new Tuple("Bob", 25); // Instantiation of a new Tuple
var name = tuple.Item1; // Assignment. name will be "Bob"
tuple.Item1 = "Kirk"; // Will not set it. It's immutable.
```

This is a 2-tuple, however, you could modify my example to support 3,4,5,6 etc. tuples.

Comment: Actually this is not a t-uple but a pair.

Comment: The `tuple` instance is still mutable, so it's technically not a tuple. For proof change `tuple.Item1 = "Steve"` then `console.log()` the output.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I have modified the example to make the Tuple immutable.

Comment: How do you modify this to support an arbitrary length?

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, he asked for destructuring

Comment: @ThatWeirdo.. no.. he hasn't asked about destructuring, but destructuring is a possible efficient solution to his problem. There are x possible solutions and every is valid, even though they vary in conciseness/simplicity

Comment: @The Minister Re-read the question. OP was searching for a syntax like `name, age = tuple` like Python has, to not "do it in the ugly way" (OP quote). This answer does not provide such a thing, it does provides a tuple look-alike, without the syntax the OP asked for, so it does not answer the question. The question was "simulate Python tuples in JS5", and this by no means looks like a Python tuple, it is a Python dict at most

Comment: @ThatWeirdo that sounds contradictory. So he asked about a python-tuple simulation but its not satisfactory to provide a tuple lookalike? I think its useful to have this option too, at least for comparison of different solutions, even if its sub-optimal.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tuple implementation that works quite well. This solution allows for array destructuring, as well as basic type-cheking.

```
const Tuple = (function() {
    function Tuple() {
        // Tuple needs at least one element
        if (arguments.length < 1) {
            throw new Error('Tuple needs at least one element');
        }

        const args = { ...arguments };

        // Define a length property (equal to the number of arguments provided)
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
            value: arguments.length,
            writable: false
        });

        // Assign values to enumerable properties
        for (let i in args) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, i, {
                enumerable: true,
                get() {
                    return args[+i];
                },
                // Checking if the type of the provided value matches that of the existing value
                set(value) {
                    if (typeof value !== typeof args[+i]) {
                        throw new Error('Cannot assign ' + typeof value + ' on ' + typeof args[+i]);
                    }

                    args[+i] = value;
                }
            });
        }

        // Implementing iteration with Symbol.iterator (allows for array destructuring as well for...of loops)
        this[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
            const tuple = this;

            return {
                current: 0,
                last: tuple.length - 1,
                next() {
                    if (this.current <= this.last) {
                        let val = { done: false, value: tuple[this.current] };
                        this.current++;
                        return val;
                    } else {
                        return { done: true };
                    }
                }
            };
        };

        // Sealing the object to make sure no more values can be added to tuple
        Object.seal(this);
    }

    // check if provided object is a tuple
    Tuple.isTuple = function(obj) {
        return obj instanceof Tuple;
    };

    // Misc. for making the tuple more readable when printing to the console
    Tuple.prototype.toString = function() {
        const copyThis = { ...this };
        const values = Object.values(copyThis);
        return `(${values.join(', ')})`;
    };

    // conctat two instances of Tuple
    Tuple.concat = function(obj1, obj2) {
        if (!Tuple.isTuple(obj1) || !Tuple.isTuple(obj2)) {
            throw new Error('Cannot concat Tuple with ' + typeof (obj1 || obj2));
        }

        const obj1Copy = { ...obj1 };
        const obj2Copy = { ...obj2 };

        const obj1Items = Object.values(obj1Copy);
        const obj2Items = Object.values(obj2Copy);

        return new Tuple(...obj1Items, ...obj2Items);
    };

    return Tuple;
})();

const SNAKE_COLOR = new Tuple(0, 220, 10);

const [red, green, blue] = SNAKE_COLOR;
console.log(green); // => 220
```