# AJAX only show the first object in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, jsonp

Main.js

```
$(function(){ 
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '//localhost:8000/secure',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }    
   });
});
```

Output.json

```
({"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"3433","content":"this is content","title":"Notice 26/6"},
{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"4261","content":"this is content","title":"Welcome"})
```

So basically when I run the code, it only show the first object

{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"3433","content":"this is content","title":"Notice 26/6"}

But the second object is not showing.

What should I do to show BOTH object (or the whole json)?

Note: I must use JSONP else i will get some weird errors...

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"3433","content":"this is content","title":"Notice 26/6"},{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"4261","content":"this is content","title":"Welcome"}]
```

if you want list of objects then you can pass something like mentioned above Note '**[**' brace instead of '**(**'.The way you are trying is python tuple way, if you want it in that format then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512405/javascript-variable-assignments-from-tuples).Hope it helps

I checked on console and this is what I see
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(){ 
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '//localhost:8000/secure',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {
        var response = eval(data);
        $.each(response, function(key, event) {
        console.log(event.d)
        }
      }    
   });
});
```

Return data like this

```
{"d":[{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"3433","content":"this is content","title":"Notice 26/6"},
{"posted_date":"25 Jun 2015 ","posted_ID":"4261","content":"this is content","title":"Welcome"}]}
```

Comment: it only return the first object but i want both :P

Comment: You can calling method add to question.And this method to return data check

Comment: method add to question?