# How do I keep track of a variable's value when it's passed into a function?

Tags: javascript, variables

Does JavaScript come with a way to keep track of a variable's identity when it's passed into a function?
For example:

```
var dog = 0;

function dogStuff(animal){
  animal = animal++;
}
```

In this example I would like to make dog == 1 by passing dog into the function:

```
dogStuff(dog);
```

such that

```
console.log(dog);
```

would print 1. People have marked this as duplicate to a couple of other questions, but those are a bit too complex for me, a beginner, to understand. I need some responses that assume I have little to no knowledge of JS.

Comment: You can't do that with primitives. What you *can* do is something like: `dog = dogStuff(dog);`

Comment: Also note that `==` is a boolean operation.

Comment: Use `window.dog++` inside `dogStuff()` function to get what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: the line `animal = animal++` won't do anything because it is a postfix increment. Either just do `animal++` or `++animal` to increment it.

---

Nope, `dog` will not be changed. JavaScript [passes primitives by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13104494/2397327) (Thanks @ASDFGerte for the correction).

```
var dog = 0;
function dogStuff(animal) {
  animal++;
}
dogStuff(dog);
console.log(dog);  // prints 0
```

What you want to do (probably) is something similar to what @alfasin mentioned: return the updated value of dog.

```
var dog = 0;
function dogStuff(animal) {
  animal++;
  return animal;
}
dog = dogStuff(dog);
console.log(dog);  // prints 1
```

However, if you pass an object and reassign its properties, the original object will be modified ([almost like pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/2397327)):

```
var dog = { age: 0 };
function incrementAge(animal) {
  animal.age++;
}
incrementAge(dog);
console.log(dog.age);  // prints 1
```

---

**edit**: If you want to assign multiple variables on return, one possible way to do it is to return an array of variables, which can then be assigned with [deconstructed assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4513061/2397327):

```
var dog = 0;
var cat = 52;
function incrementTwoAnimals(animal1, animal2) {
  animal1++;
  animal2++;
  return [animal1, animal2];
}
[dog, cat] = incrementTwoAnimals(dog, cat);  // deconstructed assignment
console.log(dog, cat);  // prints 1, 53
```

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by "reassign its properties?"

Comment: @ASDFGerte Oops, I meant say pass by value. Fixed

Comment: Note that it's "primitives are passed by value", objects are a different story again, sometimes described as "pass by copy of reference"

Comment: @ JonathanLam Thanks! What if I need a function with multiple parameters and my program has multiple variables, like dogStuff(animal1, animal2) and variables dog, cat. If in a particular case the function only updates the value of one of the two variables, how do I tell the computer which variable to change with return. Like if dogStuff(cat,dog) only does animal1++ and not animal 2++, how do I get it to update cat with return?

Comment: @Christoph I'm glad this helped! I'll add an edit about ways to do multiple assignment with return

Answer (score 1):

The function you posted did not return any value that you can use outside of it. So you need to add: return. This means that when you run dogStuff(...) it will actually return a value. And then you save that value in a variable, which can be the same dog that you passed as a parameter.

Here's the full code:

```
var dog = 0;

function dogStuff(animal){
   return animal++;
}

dog = dogStuff(dog);
```