# Should I include setState in useCallback's array of dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

    const onActiveChanged = useCallback(
      isActive => () => {
        // do something
        setActive(isActive);
      },
      [setActive], // or just [] is okay?
    );
```

When using `useState` and `useCallback` (or `useMemo`) together, should I include `setState` in the array of dependencies?

Comment: @AngelSalazar The updater method from useState isn't memoized or doesn't persist the same reference?

Comment: my bad, according to the docs "React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list."

Comment: @AngelSalazar Thanks for confirmation! I also found that part in https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/master/content/docs/hooks-reference.md So just passing an empty array must be okay. You can leave it as an answer to this question or I'll post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The recommendation for that is also on [React Docs - Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
>   state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.
>
> `setState(newState);`
>
> During subsequent re-renders, the first value
>   returned by useState will always be the most recent state after
>   applying updates.
>
> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t
>   change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
>   or useCallback dependency list.

Comment: This answer is slightly obsolete now since it refers to obsolete docs. [The new docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) actually do not promise that the setter will be stable, but maybe that's just an oversight?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `useCallback` as you rightly hinted is to [memoise](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback):

> useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps).

And as for what `useMemo` is intended for:

> You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.
>
> `const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => computeExpensiveValue(a, b), [a, b]);`

But as a rule, `useState` is stable between renders (i.e. pre-memoised), so you should not need to memoise it *again*, so [it can be safely omited from dependency callbacks](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#updating-state-from-a-memoized-callback).

The question then comes, is your 'do something' below an expensive calculation? It shouldn't be to onerous to make use of `useCallback`, but it could well be [boilerplate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) you don't need, and could make almost direct use of your `setActive` function.

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

const onActiveChanged = useCallback(
  isActive => () => {
    // do something
    setActive(isActive);
  },
  [],
);
```

Another way to prevent unnecessary dependencies, in your useCallback and other hooks, is to make use of [functional updates](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state). The result being that you can have these:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
const [expensiveCalc, setExpensiveCalc] = useState(false);

const onExpensiveCalc = useCallback(
  expensiveInput => () => {
    const newState = doExpensiveCalc(expensiveInput);
    expensiveCalc(newState);
  },
  [setActive], // here for completeness only
);

return (<>
  // expensive calculation
  <button onClick={onExpensiveCalc}>Do lengthy calculation</button>
  // cheap calculation, using functional updates
  <button onClick={() => setActive(prevBoolean => !prevBoolean)}>Cheap Set Active</button>
</>)
```

---

Do note, that there's a little [nuance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567856/react-state-set-function-in-onclick) to how set state works in an onClick, and you should make use of an arrow function, so your `setActive` is run on click, not render. This is shown in the second answer above, but without explanation.

See also: [What is useState() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165945/what-is-usestate-in-react)