# React state set function in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Learning React via a tutorial and I don't understand why I have to create a new function to pass to a JSX `onClick` and can't just use the one returned from a React `useState` call.

The below works as it calls `handleButtonClick` on the button click, but it does not work if I just pass the `setMessage` function call with a string instead.

**Works:**

```
function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('Javascript is so cool');

  function handleButtonClick() {
    setMessage('This is a new message');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Update The Message!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Does Not Work:**

```
function App() {
  //Javascript goes here
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('Javascript is so cool');

  function handleButtonClick() {
    setMessage('This is a new message');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{message}</h1>
      <button onClick={setMessage('Boom')}>Update The Message!</button>
    </div>
  );
```

I see that:
`<button onClick={() => setMessage('Boom')}>Update The Message!</button>`
works, but I don't get why it has to be setup like this and I can't just use the `setMessage` call in the same way I use the `handleButtonClick` call.

Comment: They both refer to a function rather than invoking it.  Onclick wants to know "Which functions should I call?"  So you pass the function, not its invocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's happened because when you put the function with parenthesis you call the function and if you only put the function without the parenthesis you pass the "pointer".

An example:

```
// log function
function logTheType(param) {
    console.log(typeof param);
}

// sum function
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

// sum is a function
logTheType(sum);
// res: function

// you are calling sum and send the return to the logTheType
logTheType(sum(1, 5));
// res: number

// you pass an anonymous function
logTheType(() => sum(1, 5));
// res: function
```

Answer (score 2):

Once React renders the `HTML` part then from `onClick={setMessage('Boom')}` will be evaluated in the same time. So `setMessage` function will return `undefined` which will be your `onClick` callback.

To make it work, you need to pass an anonymous function as you mentioned just like the following:

```
onClick={() => setMessage('Boom')}
```

In this way you are attaching an event to `onClick` and `setMessage` will be called once you click on the `button` and won't be executed immediately.

From [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)' documentation:

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For onClick you need to provide the callback function.

```
onClick={setMessage('Boom')} // here on render setMessage will be executed.

onClick={() => setMessage('Boom')} // here only click event setMessage will be executed
```

Answer (score 0):

In not working code you are executing `setMessage` immidiately, you should change it to be an arrow function.

If you write this `onClick={setMessage('Boom')}`, then you are executing that function right at render, because `onClick` needs a function and you are passing function (`setMessage`), but also executing it with `()`.

So if you don't need parameters, you can pass `setMessage` without `()`, because you need to pass only reference to a function.

In your case out need an arrow function, because you need an argument