# Wrap a function in useState

Tags: reactjs

" Wrap `getListViewSetting` in a function for useState ", what does this mean?

```
 const [isListView, setIsListView] = useState(
    getListViewSetting(location?.pathname?.replace('/', ''), true),
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is useState() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165945/what-is-usestate-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever (or whatever tool) said this probably meant for you to do:

```
const [isListView, setIsListView] = useState(
  () => getListViewSetting(location?.pathname?.replace('/', ''), true)
);
```

If you pass a function into `useState`, then react will call that function exactly once to determine the initial value. If `getListViewSetting` is expensive, that can be a performance improvement, because the code you had will need to call it on every render, even though the value is useless other than on the first render.