# i want to increment and decrement the number when the button from other component is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

counterScreen.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CounterScreen = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>This the number: {count}</h2>
        </div>
    ) }

export default CounterScreen
```

addButton.js

```js
import React from 'react'

const AddButton = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button>+</button>
        </div>
    ) }

export default AddButton
```

subtractButton.js

```js
import React from 'react'

const SubtractButton = () => {
    return (
       <div>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
    ) }

export default SubtractButton
```

i want when i click the button in addbutton.js the counter should add 1 and when i click the button in subtractbutton.js the counter should subtract 1

what will be the best way to share the state here please help

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could add code in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is useState() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165945/what-is-usestate-in-react)

Comment: What is relation between these 3 components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to solve this is to put the state in the containing component, and pass in values or callbacks to the relevant components:

```js
const Counter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return (
        <div>
            <CounterScreen count={count}/>
            <AddButton onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}/>
            <SubtractButton onClick={() => setCount(count-1)}/>
        </div>
    );
};

const CounterScreen = ({count}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>This the number: {count}</h2>
        </div>
    )
};

const AddButton = ({onClick}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}>+</button>
        </div>
    )
};

const SubtractButton = ({onClick}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}>-</button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: after  this do is pass only  coounter as a component in index.js since it contains other components??

Comment: You can split all four of these components into separate files if you'd like, depending on how you want to re-use them; I was just showing the functional code and not `import`/`export` etc.

Comment: it actually worked for me thanks again i am getting a bit better understanding now  thanks again