# React readOnlyError.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: "searchData" is read-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

As you can see in the code below that while typing or searching, the user also searches the data in the database for what the user is typing.

```
  const searchData = useState();
  const fetchSearchPerson = async (name) => {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: SEARCH_PERSON,
      variables: {
        name: name
      },
    })
     searchData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve (data); 
      }, 1000);
    });
    return data;
  };

.....

  fetchSearchPerson(params.suggestTerm)
  return searchData.map((data) => {
    console.log("datas: ", data)
  });
 .....
```

Error I have encountered so far:

[image]

UPDATE

```
const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState();
  
  const fetchSearchPerson = async (name) => {
   
    const { data } = await client.query({
      
      query: SEARCH_PEOPLE,
      variables: {
        name: name,
      },
    })
    const searchDataPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve (data); 
      }, 1000);
    });
    setSearchData(searchDataPromise); // add this
    return data;
  };

 fetchSearchPerson(params.suggestTerm)
 return searchData.map((data) => {
    console.log("datas: ", data)
  })
```

I dont received the error but the result from the search data

Comment: const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState();

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, ive tried to changed `const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState(); ` but i get the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is useState() in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165945/what-is-usestate-in-react)

Comment: @kaito you can use  useState callback to set value to searchData.

Comment: @MattU unfortunately no

Comment: @MaiTruong can you show me your solutions?

Comment: @MattU can you please open my question please? since the link you've comment here is not answer my question, thanks