# How can I take information from one component in react and use it to change the content of other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Good day,

I´m learning React using function components and I have 2 components and the App.js file that look something like this:

---

**App.js**

```
import Container from './components/Container';
import InfoBox from './components/InfoBox';

function App() {


  return (
    <div>
      <InfoBox content='test info box content'/>
      <Container text='Charles Darwin' />
      <Container text='Alexander The Great' />
      <Container text='Nichola Tesla' />
      <Container text='Aristoteles' />
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

---

---

**Container.js**

```
function Container(props) {
    return (
        <div className = 'containerDiv'>
            <p className = 'containerText'
              /*onMouseEnter={functionToChangeContent}
              onMouseLeave={functionToHideContent}*/  
            >
                {props.text}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Container;
```

---

---

**infoBox.js**

```
function InfoBox (props) {
    return (
        <div className='infoBox'>
            <p>
                {props.content}
            </p>
        </div>

    );
}
export default InfoBox;
```

---

I want to change the content of the InfoBox component when hovering a Container component

What I wanna do it´s that so when I hover a the Container of a person in the website, the content of the InfoBox will change to show information about that person but for now I want to start with something little like just changing the content to the name of the person (the props.text of the Container) but I have just managed to do this by rendering the InfoBox into the Container component using functions with the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave and states; but that means that the InfoBox doesn´t appear when entering the first time the page and will only exist after hovering for the first time a Container. Or by adding the "onMouseEnter/Leave" at every Container in the App.js but I feel it will be better to just do that in the Container module to make it more practical and easy to read.
(The "onMouseEnter/Leave" in the Container component are commented and point to no real function because that´s just a failed test I wanted to do but to show what I´m trying to achieve)

It´s there a better way to connect these components so I can render the InfoBox in the App.js but still change it´s content when hovering a Container?

Answer (score 0):

Try using react's `useState` [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165945/what-is-usestate-in-react)

You can pass a parent's `set_foo` funciton (from `[foo, set_foo] = useSatate(default_value)` to child components. The children can call `set_foo` which updates `foo` in the parent.

In this case, we are only setting a string in the parent. However, you could set an object with more details for your use case, but I think this will lead you down the right path :)

This is not the only way (and probably not the best way), but this could work, for exmaple:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [name, set_name] = useState(''); // magic of useState !
  
  return (
    <div>
      <InfoBox content={`test info box content. Name: ${name}`}/>
      <Container text='Charles Darwin' set_name={set_name} />
      <Container text='Alexander The Great' set_name={set_name} />
      <Container text='Nichola Tesla' set_name={set_name}/>
      <Container text='Aristoteles' set_name={set_name}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Container(props) {
    return (
        <div className = 'containerDiv'>
            <p className = 'containerText'
              onMouseEnter={() => props.set_name(props.text)} // set
              onMouseLeave={() => props.set_name('')} // clear
            >
                {props.text}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

function InfoBox (props) {
    return (
        <div className='infoBox'>
            <p>
                {props.content}
            </p>
        </div>

    );
}
```

[Demo](https://playcode.io/1634710)

Comment: Wow, this it´s awesome, I didn´t knew I could use a state like that. But the part on the App.js where you write the text "${name}"; it´s that something native to react? because it looks kind of similar to JQuery (by the way, would you recommend to combine both or it will be unnecessary? sorry if this question should go in a separated post)

Comment: Thats string interpolation. In js i can write: \`Hi, this is ${name}\`, and it would replace name with its value. Remember the backticks tho ``.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. You can maintain the state in the App.jsx and pass the getters and setters down the components via prop drilling. However the best way is probably to use React's inbuilt context.

**React Context version (recommended)**

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const context = React.createContext(null);

function InfoBox () {
  const { value } = React.useContext(context);
    return (
        <div className='infoBox'>
            <p>
                {value}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

function Container(props) {
    const { setValue } = React.useContext(context);

    return (
        <div className = 'containerDiv'>
            <p className = 'containerText'
              onMouseEnter={() => setValue(props.text)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setValue("none")}
            >
                {props.text}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export function App() {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState('none');
  return (
    <div>
      <context.Provider value={{ value: content, setValue: setContent }}>
        <InfoBox />
        <Container text='Charles Darwin' />
        <Container text='Alexander The Great' />
        <Container text='Nichola Tesla' />
        <Container text='Aristoteles' />
       </context.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-pond-g8f863?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Damn, that looks awesome; I have been researching about the context provider and It looks very flexible in some ways, actually with this I can set the functions directly in the Container.js instead of adding multiple properties to each Container call in the App.js
Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Do mark this answer as accepted if it works for you :)