# How to use TypeScript declaration files alongside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, declaration

I want to separate my JavaScript function documentation into TypeScript .d.ts files.

For example:

```
components/
  Button/
    Button.jsx   # JavaScript component
    Button.d.ts  # TypeScript documentation with prop types
```

Similarly how Material UI does this. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button

My issue is that TypeScript & VSCode does not recognize the `.d.ts` file for the current JavaScript file.

In my setup, I have the following `Button.d.ts` file:

```
interface Props {
  text: string
  onClick: () => void
}

declare const Button: (props: Props) => Element

export default Button
```

and the following `Button.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react'

const Button = ({ text, onClick }) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>
}

export default Button
```

But VSCode is not recognising the prop types in the component:

[image: Screenshot]

---

How can I set up my project (maybe tsconfig.json file) to accept the use of corresponding .d.ts file?

*My current tsconfig.json config:*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 2
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Can you try export `Prop` interface?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki didn't seem to fix it

Comment: does renaming `Button.d.ts` to `index.d.ts` work?

Comment: @SreetamDas unfortunately not. I tried renaming both files to index and they did not work still.

Comment: I don't believe what you're asking is possible. The `.d.ts` intellisense does not appear because they are `pre-compilation` files which is of no use in JavaScript. `tsconfig.json` is for the Typescript compiler's configuration and will not impact JavaScript files.

Comment: The TypeScript team recommends against this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

I'd recommend porting your source files to TypeScript, otherwise your declaration files will not be checked against your code and they could break very easily or get out of date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**if you want to use it in your local project**

in `tsconfig.json` remove `"src/**/*"` add `"src/**/*.d.ts"` instead, then js files won't be parsed as `any` type and their definition will be included:

```
{
  ...,
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
  ...,
}
```

put `.jsx` and `.d.ts` in the same dir under the same name as `Button.jsx` and `Button.d.ts` for example.

Use it in any `.ts` file, for example `./src/usage.ts` if `components` are under `src` too:

```js
import Button from './components/Button/Button';

const b1 = Button({
    text: '123',
    onClick: () => {
        console.log('here');
    },
});

const b2 = Button({
    text: 123, // fails - it's not a string.
    onClick: () => {
        console.log('here');
    },
});
```

[image]

**If you want to serve it as a library**

In your `package.json` you need to add

```
{
  ...,
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  ...,
}
```

and then in `index.d.ts`

```js
/// <amd-module name="package-name" />
export * from './other-files-with-declarations';
```

Comment: Then provided information isn't sufficient, is it an option for you to share source code or to invite to the repo?

Comment: it seems to be working now! Congrats, I think I'll reward you - let me just do some testing real quick.

Comment: Awesome, let me know if you need further assistance here. Check if it builds correctly, I think this is the only part change of `includes` can affect.

Comment: I get the type coming up in VSCode when importing my component in App.jsx, but running `yarn tsc` does not come up with any kind of warnings... Would you happen to know how to make TypeScript complain when the types don't match?

Comment: yes, usually they (VSC and tsc) should use the same tsconfig, you can specify it as an argument. Because time to time you can meet a situation when VSC is more strict than tsc or otherwise. Once you specify the same config everywhere it should show you the same errors.

Comment: one last thing... the types seem to work in other files when importing it such as from App.jsx... but the types are `any` in the `Button.jsx` file itself.

Comment: Yep, because it is a `js` file and you are in `js` mode there, where all vars can be anything. If you want to have types you need write the project as TS one, then you don't need `.d.ts` etc, it will be generated based on `tsx`. Try to remove `.d.ts` and rename `.jsx` to `.tsx` and define type there. It should work too. More info is here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Comment: I will reward the bounty when I can (in 22 hrs)

Comment: Great! Thanks! And happy coding!

Comment: Hi there, is everything fine with the answer?

Comment: @satanTime is there a way to do same thing with `.tsx` & `.d.ts` together? (for example, Button.tsx and Button.d.ts). What I want to do is separating documentation part from implementation part.

Comment: you should try to use `.jsx` instead of `.tsx`, because `.tsx` supersedes `.d.ts`.