# //@ts-check and DOM element properties gives an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-check

I've got some simple browser-side JS code, and thought I'd try using @ts-check to pick out any fluff. Some valid bugs were found, and I've added js-doc parameter type information as well. I don't want a transpile step so this needs to be vanilla Javascript.

When I access DOM element properties I get errors, because TS doesn't know the real type of these elements.

```
s.YWindows = document.getElementById("rows-input").valueAsNumber
```

gives...

```
Property 'valueAsNumber' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

I thought I could use a JSDoc type hint to resolve that, but it only moves the problem.

```
     /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    let r =  document.getElementById("rows-input")
    s.YWindows = r.valueAsNumber
```

```
Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 52 more.
```

Suggestions, or do I just have to disable around this section somehow?

Comment: This question seems very similar: [TypeScript checks and declarations in regular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69890337/215552). Perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler supports [inline type casting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts) when using JSDoc syntax. From the link:

> TypeScript borrows cast syntax from Google Closure. This lets you cast types to other types by adding a `@type` tag before any parenthesized expression.
>
> ```js
> /**
>  * @type {number | string}
>  */
> var numberOrString = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : 100;
> var typeAssertedNumber = /** @type {number} */ (numberOrString);
> ```
>
> You can even cast to `const` just like TypeScript:
>
> ```js
> let one = /** @type {const} */(1);
> ```

Here's an example which addresses the details in your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=true&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcE8AcCm4DeLwE0DqBLAdgCYD2A7gM4D8AXOHgK4C2ARogE7gC+H4IwAUAGMieMtHBlwAXlQcA3Hz7Bg4AJLQA5BLxExZAIYAzZNCLg9ZMo2MALPWOjXkKgCLhEADxyiJ+cA+TEAlZ40AA0ispkpvQANjHgDHSi4Czg+AIxdASIBGl4fo7gdHg4wlSCwsn48HRi0qAQMAjIKAASACoAsgAyKng10ACiMYgMiCHgAD60dHHcvAAUgcHQAHQA5ohDI2MhAEKwKgQLAESspGQAtNW1JwCUd-J8OAbgCzfQd6h84OKr2PhiORZOAlDNmGwpkVCIgDPgcj8-gDCBcpHkBqsAG56TKIACCZAAcowWKx5L8yP9cCjgaDlPQIaw+BwFJTkUCyCCwQzSVDitk4XgEUA)

```js
/** @type {{ YWindows?: number }} */
const s = {};

// It's not safe to assume that the ID exists in the document,
// so null must be included in the union:
const input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement | null} */(document.getElementById("rows-input"));

if (input) {
  s.YWindows; // number | undefined
  s.YWindows = input.valueAsNumber;
  s.YWindows; // number
}

s.YWindows; // number | undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It is (currently) not possible to have TypeScript understand this situation. The `@types` hint applies to the variable being declared, but do not change the return type of the function that initializes its value.

You can use `//@ts-ignore` just above a line to have TS ignore *all* errors that can occur in this line. For example :

```js
/** @type {{HTMLInputElement}} */
//@ts-ignore
let r =  document.getElementById("rows-input");

s.YWindows = r.valueAsNumber;
```

This would still tell to TS that `r` has an `HTMLInputElement` type, but it will ignore the mismatch between `r`'s type and `getElementById`'s return type.
One drawback of that is that you may end up using `//@ts-ignore` quite often.

Comment: I'm after a JS solution that doesn't involve transpiling, but still give me hints/warnings in VS Code

Comment: @Roddy I indeed misread your question, sorry. I don't think you can actually avoid TS from thinking it's an error. You can use `//ts-ignore` just above the lines where TS finds false errors to have it ignore them. I'll edit my answer.