# TypeScript/VSCode bug? Building key names from const arrays don't show the correct Intellisense options

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following function in a typescript file:

```js
export function buildEnvTests<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(environments: T) {
    const r = {} as {[K in T[number] as `is${K}`]: () => boolean};
    for (let e of environments) {
        r[`is${e}`] = () => '' === e;
    }
    return r;
}
```

If I were to import this function into a TS file, Intellisense in VS Code correctly reports the derived keys in the return value.  For example:

```js
import { buildEnvTests } from "./test.js";

const x = ['A', 'B', 'C'] as const;
const r = buildEnvTests(x);
r. // Here, properties named isA, isB and isC show up as expected.
```

If I do the same in a JavaScript file, however, I get no suggestions:

```js
import { buildEnvTests } from "./test.js";

const x = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
const r = buildEnvTests(x);
r. // Here:  No Intellisense.
```

Comment: If you define `x` using inline `cost` type casting using JSDoc, you'll see the expected IntelliSense suggestions: `const x = /** @type {const} */ (["A", "B", "C"]);` [Example Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLrZew). I've answered a similar question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72325965/438273), so I'll link it as a duplicate target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [//@ts-check and DOM element properties gives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72325104/ts-check-and-dom-element-properties-gives-an-error)

Comment: Thanks.  Good workaround.  However, the question remains:  Is this a bug?  Because I should not be forced to add the JsDoc comment for it to work, correct?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77508382/typescript-vscode-bug-building-key-names-from-const-arrays-dont-show-the-corre?noredirect=1#comment136643644_77508382) It’s not a bug. The TS compiler needs some kind of annotation in order to differentiate between an array of strings and a readonly tuple of string literals: the array literal syntax (square brackets) is ambiguous by itself.

Comment: @jsejcksn thanks for dropping by.  I am no expert in TS/JS since I specialize in backend C#, so correct me if I'm wrong:  I, as a developer, had the expectation to have the same experience in JS and TS while using a fully typed library.  I am experiencing a difference and this is why I ask.  The TS in the library is providing everything, including the fact that the string array is **const**.  It is strange to me that while all the information is there, VS Code refuses to provide Intellisense.  You'll say now that not all information is there, but since it's JS you can't expect it all.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your function like this

```
export function buildEnvTests<T extends string>(environments: ReadonlyArray<T>) {
    const r = {} as Record<`is${T}`, () => boolean>;
    for (let e of environments) {
        r[`is${e}`] = () => '' === e;
    }
    return r;
}
```

[TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwEZKYA2AJgKIoBuAKsAM4x0A81coMwKJdcDUmKAOYA+ABSdKmKDgC2nRgC44AJWABDEjiIBPAIJQoa7S2EBKOAG8AUHFtw0OBnChwAvJYC+cNT1UOoJEwABph0ACQW1B5BADRwouauwvgQEETqKMIA3DZ2CNDx6fDAcBAIbFRSsvJ05tZ2Dc4A2iHhFsDRALpu8YnJAOT9bq7uwDkNHrm2UMAwSFC4UDmTVg4oThwMAArSJAAiwJQ9BMTkVLQMdKJN-QeUwEQQYHIoMP1x-TsQJEgY2Cj9TqmKwAehBjTgAD0APxwKxWTYwL77Q4AOlCdweTxeMASoPBELsMPhiORd3RdGRvywODxYMJROh8IR9CRu3JoQAyjA1IIBII6QSGTCgA)

Comment: Using a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) with the original function signature will preserve the type information just fine when the argument is an object (array) literal. TypeScript's inference works differently when a function's argument is an object literal compared to an unannotated object variable type. The problem in the question centers around this fact (specifically as it relates to using JSDoc annotations for types in JavaScript files). Here's an example: https://tsplay.dev/WGYEKN