# How to check types for JavaScript by ".d.ts" files with the same names as them

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am coding with a NodeJS project in VS Code. The core code is in JavaScript and the declarations are written in ".d.ts" files. ESlint is enabled to enforce code style.

What I want is:

- to check types for the JavaScript files when **editing them in VS Code** (not only when importing them as modules)
- and it's better **not** to use `/** @type {import('./utils').Rectangle} */` because it may bring a long `@type` string.

The project structure is as below:

```
workspace/
  .eslintrc
  tsconfig.json
  utils.js
  utils.d.ts
```

`utils.d.ts` is like (this code refers to another Stack Overflow question, but I can't find it):

```js
export type Rectangle = {
  width: number,
  height: number
};

export as namespace _Utils;
```

`utils.js` is like:

```js
/** @type {_Utils.Rectangle} */
let rect;
```

And VS Code returns ts(2552) "Cannot find name `_Utils`" in the hover information of `_Utils.Rectangle`.

`tsconfig.json` is as below (referring to [How to use TypeScript declaration files alongside JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932377/how-to-use-typescript-declaration-files-alongside-javascript)):

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2021",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 2
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

`.eslintrc` is as below:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        // "linebreak-style": [
        //     "error",
        //     "windows"
        // ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": "**/*.ts",
            "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
            "extends": [
                "eslint:recommended",
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
            ],
            "plugins": [
                "@typescript-eslint"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So what should I do next?