# How to document tuple using JSDoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Is there some sort of standard to document tuples using JSDoc?

Given the following code, is this the correct way to document values at specific index positions in array?

```
/**
 * @param {Array.<number,number>} tuple_variable description
 * @param {number} tuple_variable[0] description
 * @param {number} tuple_variable[1] description
 */
function document_tuple( tuple_variable: [number,number] ) {
   // omitted
}
```

Comment: You could use `@typedef` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#typedef-callback-and-param. BTW starting from Typescript 4 you can label tuple elements https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements

Answer (score 10):

If you want a fully-expanded version that includes descriptions of each array element, something like this will work:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {number} MyTupleIndex0 - Description of index 0...
 * @typedef {number} MyTupleIndex1 - Description of index 1...
 * @typedef {[MyTupleIndex0, MyTupleIndex1]} MyTuple
 * @param {MyTuple} tuple_variable
 */
function document_tuple(tuple_variable) {
  // ommited
}
```

Or, more tersely, but without the descriptions:

```js
/**
 * @param {[number, number]} tuple_variable
 */
function document_tuple(tuple_variable) {
  // ommited
}
```