# Zapier dynamic dropdown using Zapier UI

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am working on Zapier App using zapier UI, for which I require dynamic drop-down for one of my trigger,

I have tried many things still getting errors,
finally I have also tried to add static response for drop-down, still getting same error,

```
let custom_result = {};
custom_result['status'] = '1';
custom_result['data'] = ["8453930101","8453930112","8453930103","8042073178"];
custom_result['id'] = 1;

return [custom_result];
```

Please check these screenshots and help me out,

1. Static response for drop-down list and output definition: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31827069?key=54843cbfe3130f6c7a6969f493291912
2. Dynamic drop-down settings: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31827093?key=e1ea8924d1d987b11c40c7fc2623d472
3. Error: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31827099?key=403bdb74827db0d49bb3e8e03d387777

Comment: Note: I am not using Zapier CLI as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference to tuples](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list/)

[Reference to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512405/javascript-variable-assignments-from-tuples)

```
let custom_result = {};
custom_result['status'] = '1';
custom_result['data'] = Object.freeze(["8453930101","8453930112","8453930103","8042073178"]);
custom_result['id'] = 1;

return [custom_result];
```